# Sum/Group rows into totals for each day

Tags: sql

I have some data in a table that looks like this.

[image]

Each record shows a job that was completed and on what day.

Im trying to get an output that shows how many jobs were completed today 
The query would look at how many jobs where done on the same day, and them SUM it up in a total. Ideally this is what I would like.

[image]

Whats the best way to do this in a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID,
       COUNT(*)
FROM yourTable
WHERE CompletedDate > DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0)
Group by UserID
```

Comment: This for some reason returned nothing? (no records)

Comment: Actually apologies - I think this works, I've just realised it's gone midnight now. So there will be now jobs as of yet!

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT 
        USERID,COUNT(*) AS TASK_COMPLETED 
FROM 
        YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE 
        Convert(varchar(11), COMPLETED,101) = Convert(varchar(11), getdate(),101)
GROUP BY  
        USERID
```

Comment: This didnt work - all I got was: 'TRUNC' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: which db you are using ?? trunc is function of oracle

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UserID, count(UserID)
FROM MyTable 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,Completed,GETDATE()) = 0
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: I like what you did with the DATEDIFF. I never thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id,count(completed),completed from table
where completed = to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yy') group by completed
```